How to remove deceptive pages from my WordPress blog?
I have a WordPress blog and recently I got an error on my Google Search Console that my website has some deceptive pages. Google also gave me the links to those pages.

I want to remove these pages and I haven't added these in the first place.
I tried but couldn't find the source of these pages as well as how to remove them.
Can anyone please help me with these?
I tried checking my pages and the source of these pages in my WordPress pages.

I suspect if you(or one of your plugins) put these links in sitemap

Start here: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

checked sitemap and checked plugins also

Thanks, guys it is resolved, turns out there was a hidden folder uploaded by a hacker in my website's root folder. I removed it and checked on the search console as well
